# < IE8 error : 'polygonOptions.fillColor' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8, google-fusion-tables

I have created a fusion table with some data and polygons. I am styling it using google Maps API. Here is [link to the website](http://camconnect.org/interactive-map/). It is working perfectly fine in latest browsers andalso in IE 9  but in `< IE 8` I am getting this error :

```
Webpage error details :

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

Message: 'polygonOptions.fillColor' is null or not an object
```

Comment: you expect that we inspect a minified script? post some readable code.

Comment: @Dr.Molle, I am sorry, I have decompress the scipt. May be it will be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over an array with a method that iterates over object-properties:

```
for (t in e)
```

this will result in unexpected behaviour, because this may also return names of built-in-properties, e.g. names of array-methods(for me IE stops when t is "map")

Use

```
for (var t=0; t<e.length; ++t)
```

to iterate over the items of the array